# how to empty array, if use same function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i make one function for use on three place in my code. I don't like repeat code. Here is function for get budget for selected items.

```
var getBudgetForAll = function(){
                            var bId = [];
                                        angular.forEach($scope.myCartItems, function (value, key) {
                                            bId.push(value.id);
                                        });
                                        $http.get(serviceBase + 'xxxx/' + $rootScope.user_id + '/xxxxx/calculate/max-budget/from/' +
                                                $scope.ctrl.picker4.date + '/to/' + $scope.ctrl.picker5.date + '?smartb=' + benchId.join())
                                                .success(function (maxBudget)
                                                {
                                                    $scope.maxBudget = maxBudget;

                                                });

                        }
```

Now, i use this function in three place in my code

```
 $scope.allSelectedb = function () {
                             var onebyOneAddedB = getOnebyOneAddedB($scope.myCartItems);
                                $scope.myCartItems = [];
                                $scope.maxBudget = []; //here i try empty maxBudget
                            if ($scope.filteredCountries !== undefined) {
                                $scope.maxBudget = []; //here i try empty
                                $scope.myCartItems = [];
                                 addNonDuplicateItems($scope.filteredCountries); 
                                 addNonDuplicateItems(onebyOneAddedB);
                                 getBudgetForAll(); //here i call function

                            }
                            if ($scope.filteredStates !== undefined) {
                                $scope.maxBudget = []; //here i try empty
                                $scope.myCartItems = [];
                                $scope.myCartItems = $scope.filteredStates;
                                addNonDuplicateItems($scope.filteredStates);
                                addNonDuplicateItems(onebyOneAddedB);
                                getBudgetForAll(); //here i call function
                            }
                            if ($scope.filteredCities !== undefined) {
                                $scope.maxBudget = []; //here i try empty
                                $scope.myCartItems = [];
                                addNonDuplicateItems($scope.filteredCities);
                                addNonDuplicateItems(onebyOneAddedB);
                                getBudgetForAll(); //here i call function
                            }
                        };
```

I have three options, first i select country, and press GET ALL, and in $scope.maxBudget i get max budget for all items in country. If i want state, after selected country i we need select state, and press GET ALL, and get max budget for items in state...same for city.
PROBLEM: 
**on select COUNTRY** - max budget is ok
**on select STATE** - GET ALL button make get request again for country and for state, and set on **$scope.maxBudget**, sometimes budget for country and sometimes for state.
**on select CITY** - same like **STATE**, on GET ALL, i have get request for COUNTRY, for STATE and for CITY, and set **$scope.maxBudget** sometimes for country, for state and for city. in my code, you can see, i try do empty **$scope.maxBudget**, but thisdon't work.

Comment: @Rajesh thnx for your comment. Can you give me more details for this? Thnx

Comment: I only read the title and commented accordingly. In my understanding, first you do have redundant code in `allSelectedb`. Second you should use `if.. else if... else` and not `if... if... if...`

Answer (score 0):

thnx @rajesh for your hint. I fix this very easy, i only need to put

> getBudgetForAll();

out from if :)